# Combining fixed HTML with Umbraco 7 Grid content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout, umbraco7

I'm new to umbraco, and I've encountered the following problem.
I have a design with a fixed navigation box on the left. The right side is for content. This content needs to be filled with the new grid-layout from umbraco.

But the grid-container keeps getting the full width of the site. So together with the navigation-box, it pushes outside my site.

Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkdf1.jpg

I've tried the following html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
     <ul>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("ArticleContent")
  </div>
</div>
```

But the GetGridHtml places a complete full width container inside my column. Setting the container to 10 columns (and the row configs too) within umbraco doesn't help either.

Anybody know a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the solution could be to make your grid row configuration only span ten rows? I don't have enough rep in here (yet) to just comment, sorry.

Comment: That doesn't help. It still keeps adding a "container"-class div to the content which is 1170px wide.

And I can't set the container width to a smaller number in the css because there is a container-div around my complete website too.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, okay, that actually makes sense :-s If you're sure that the left side nav will be present on ALL pages, you could consider looking into altering the Views/Partials/Grid/Bootstrap3.cshtml file (it is responsible for rendering the grid)? Or, if all else fails, create a macro that can be inserted on all pages (very, very last resort, I guess).

Comment: I have thought of that too yeah, but sadly, some templates have the fixed navigation, and others don't :(

Comment: I guess you could have a "Hide left nav" flag on the document type that you might be able to use inside the Bootstrap3.cshtml file, maybe?

Comment: If it is an option, you could create a seperate Grid-template with the fixed navigation and call it whenever you need it like `@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("propertyAlias", "mycustomview")` as explained [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/using-umbraco/backoffice-overview/property-editors/built-in-property-editors-v7/Grid-Layout/Render-Grid-In-Template)